# On my Local Host, Error loading notebook - Notebook does not appear to be JSON

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to `Python`. I wanted to create a simple "Hello World" program in notebook. 
For that, I created a file named `dataAna.ipynb` in `C:\Python27` directory.

when i executed `jupyter notebook` in my Command prompt. 
When I am opening the file '`dataAna.ipynb`' on my localhost, It is showing the following Error.

```
Unreadable Notebook: C:\Python27\dataAna.ipynb NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON: u''...",)
```

[image: Screenshot of the Error: jupyter notebook on my localhost]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most basic question I've seen on Stackoverflow. I'll help you out but maybe just search for a getting started guide next time...

I was able to reproduce your "problem" by creating an empty file and naming it to *.ipynb. I also created a notebook file like it was intended to be created via the "New" button
[image]

I noticed that the empty manually created file was empty but the file created via "New" button was not. It contained the following content:

```
{
 "cells": [],
 "metadata": {},
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

Seems that's the minimal information for an empty Notebook file. I won't remember it because I like to use the "New" button

type "jupyter notebook" in terminal and see screenshot above